# How to handle different toolbars between fragments when using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to add a collapsing toolbar in a fragment and a normal toolbar in another. How can I accomplish that when using Navigation Components?

I've already read some articles saying that each toolbar should be part of the fragment layout, but it seems wrong. And I couldn't find anything about it on documentation.
Also, I saw something about `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(Toolbar, NavController)`. But I can't figure it out how to properly use it.

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing.